# Do I need to call Release() on D3D objects when I use them in another function?

Tags: c++, directx9

For example, I have an `IDirect3DSurface9 * Surface` and `IDirect3DSurface9 *BackBuffer`.

If I were to use them directly in the `render_frame` function, I would need to release them on the `closeD3D` function. However, if I use them in a function in same file or in another .h and .cpp file, when I call `Release` in `closeD3D` it gives me an error.

So, do I not need to release them if I'm using them in a function, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This text indicates there are some things about programming your are misunderstanding. "use them on a void" doesn't really make sense. :(

Comment: You are incorrectly referring to a function as "void." "void" is an incomplete type and instances of it cannot be created, so it's never correct to refer to it as a noun in the sense you have. I've corrected the terminology in your question text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules for whether or not you should call `Release` on a D3D object are simple:

It is your responsibility to *balance* your calls to functions that increase reference counts with those that decrease reference counts. Explicitly calling `AddRef`, for example, should be balanced by a call to `Release` when you are finished with that reference.

Most functions that create or get resources from somewhere implicitly increment the reference count, which means you should call `Release` when you are done with that reference to the object. The documentation for a given function will note if it does not increase the reference count.

These rules apply regardless of the function the object was created in or with, used in, and so on. They are more about the higher-level semantics of your program: generally if you allocate a bunch of resources in a startup function, you should clean those up (call `Release`) in a matching shutdown function. But if you allocate or acquire a resource temporarily within one specific function, you should release it within that function, unless you know another matching function in your codebase will be able to safely release the resource instead.

If you are getting "errors" when you move the release calls around, you've probably unbalanced the add/release reference count pairs. Or you have another sort of bug. Either way, however, "debug my code" questions are off-topic here so you'll need to resort to the old-fashioned means of problem solving: your debugger.